# Not able to perform operation (yank, delete, etc.) on custom text object from script

Tags: vim

I have created a custom text object for markdown links. I am able to perform operations (yank, delete, etc.) on the text object from normal mode but trying to do the same from within a script or command mode doesn't work.

Here's the code to create the custom object:

```
function! markdown#InLink()
    let l:magic = &magic
    set magic

    let l:currentLineNumber = line('.')

    " markdown link regex pattern
    let l:pattern = '\[[^\]]\+\]([^)]\+)'

    " move cursor to end of the markdown link
    if (!search(l:pattern, 'ce', l:currentLineNumber))
        " if it fails, there was not match on the line, so return prematurely
        return
    endif

    " start visually selecting from end of the markdown link
    normal! v

    " move cursor to beginning of the markdown link
    call search(l:pattern, 'cb', l:currentLineNumber)

    " restore magic
    let &magic = l:magic
endfunction

xnoremap <silent> il :<c-u>call markdown#InLink()<cr>
onoremap <silent> il :<c-u>call markdown#InLink()<cr>
```

Following is the function in which I am trying to yank a markdown link:

```
function! markdown#YankLink()
    normal! yil
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>yl :call markdown#YankLink()<CR>
```

`<Leader>yl` doesn't yank the link but pressing `yil` in normal mode works as expected. I tried doing it from command mode as well `:execute 'normal! yil'` but it didn't work either. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help :normal` says:

```
If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
```

Since your custom pseudo-text object is a mapping, calling it with `:normal!` can't really be expected to work.

You only need to remove the bang after `normal`:

```
function! markdown#YankLink()
    normal yil
endfunction
```